# android - web api sending/receiving an image

Tags: c#, android, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm sure it's a common question, and I probably find solutions to this but I didn't understand them. Besides I'm doing this completely blind. Another point is: I don't want to use third party libraries.

I need to send an image from my Android app to my server via c# rest webservice.

I watched this method to convert the bitmap to a byte[].

```
public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, outputStream);       
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

And here I have two (at least) problems:

1. How to send it as JSON? I tried Base64.encode() with COMMON and URLSAFE (or something like that) flags and I get error at server side: Not a valid Base64.
2. Then I suppose the client side it's ok, so how do I manage to receive and process the byte[]? Now it seems it try to convert automatically and it fails, maybe because client sends invalid data or well... I don't know.

I can't provide code right now (in fact I think I don't have code to do this at all), but I'll update with what I have if required.

Thanks and sorry for this horrible made question

Answer (score 0):

**Android :**

```
byte[] content = getBitmapAsByteArray(bitmap);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(content));           
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**c#.net**

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for answering. Second, Android part it's all deprecated.